# jsp page not working: I corrected the variable requespath in the debug but the result is the same

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I tried to solve the problem with the solutions found in the forum, but I have been stuck here for weeks.
I tried to put the jsp files in the WEB-INF folder and delete the error pages I had defined, also modifying the path configuration files and the beans.xml file, but I was returning the old 404 and circular path errors that I had solved. So I put everything back as before, the jsp files in the webapp folder. I think the error is in the xml file. When I click enter on the button, the result should appear on a second page, in the xml file this page has the same class, but I read that if I use the jsp-file tag, there is no need to name the class. I tried with action = "lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp" in the button, but it didn't work, I tried with href, I tried with redirect, I tried with the reset button, I tried with window.location.href but in the android package there is no it was the window variable and I dropped it, it's not an mvc app, it should use hibernate which is automatic and doesn't need filter, listener and a thousand other configuration files.
In debugging the page is redirected elsewhere, but I have corrected the value and the result is the same.
Thanks to who helps me.

The really strange thing is that during the debug I found doing the watch of the variables, in the request tree -> coyoterequest -> uriMB -> byteC - buff ->
many arrays of 100 ascii characters [0..99] containing:
GET /lista_parlamentari_cirocoscrizione.jsp/circoscrizione=Calabria HTTP/1.1
host:localhost:8080
connection:keep-alivve
sec-ch-ua:"Chromeium";
v="106" ,"Google Chrome" ;v="106" , "Not;A=Brand";v="qq""
sec-ch-ua-mobile:?00
sec-ch-ua-platform:"Windows""
upgrade-insecure-requests:11
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0 Safari/537.366
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/Webp,image/apn g,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-eXchange;v=b3;q=0.99
sec-fetch-site:same-originn
sec-fetch-mode:navigatee
sec-fetch-user:?11
sec-fetch-dest:documentt
referer:http://localhost:8080/cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione.jspp
accept-encoding:gpip, deflate, brr
accept-language:it-IT,it;q=0.9,en- US;q=0.8,en;q=0.77
cookie:JSESSIONID=401...

which I had to translate by hand, WHILE in the response variable tree I found the code of the page cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione.jsp and half of the code of the page index.jsp and this does not make sense.

beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<absolute-ordering>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</absolute-ordering>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
 
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/webapp/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/webapp/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
 
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>ParlamentareController</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Parlamento</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AggiugiParlamentare</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AggiugiParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AggiugiParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addParlamentare</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>CercaParlamentareDalPartito</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CercaParlamentareDalPartito</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CercaParlamentareDalPartito</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getParlamentare3</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione.jsp</jsp-file>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>indexcontroller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>indexcontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.IndexController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>indexcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   
  <!--  
   <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione</display-name>
    <servlet-name>lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp</jsp-file>
     
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  -->
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsptest</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsptest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
  
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>error</display-name>
    <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
    
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
   <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>error</display-name>
    <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
  
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.IndexController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>src/main/resources/static/error</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dal_nome</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dal_nome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Cerca_parlamentare_dal_nome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getParlamentare</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AggiornaParlamentare</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AggiornaParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AggiornaParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/updateParlamentare</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>CancellaParlamentare</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CancellaParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CancellaParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cancellaParlamentare</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LeggiParlamentare</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LeggiParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LeggiParlamentare</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/parlamentare/{nome}</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ListaParlamentari</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ListaParlamentari</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListaParlamentari</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lista_parlamentari</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ListaPeriodiCariche</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ListaPeriodiCariche</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListaPeriodiCariche</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lista_periodi_cariche</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Parlamentari</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Parlamentari</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Parlamentari</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/parlamentari</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/webapp/WEB-INF/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>

</web-app>
```

ParlamentareController.java

```
    @GetMapping("/cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione")
    public ModelAndView getParlamentare4(@RequestParam("circoscrizione") String 
 circoscrizionee)
{
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Parlamentare> parlamentari = 
 parlamRepo.findByCircoscrizione(circoscrizionee);
        mv.addObject(parlamentari);
        mv.setViewName("lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp");
        
                return mv;  
    }
```

cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione.jsp

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cerca un parlamentare dalla circoscrizione</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Ricerca parlamentare in base alla circoscrizione:</h2>


 <form  method="POST" action="\lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp"  modelAttribute="parlamentari"> 
<table>
<tr>
<td>Circoscrizione:</td>

  <td> <input type="text" name="circoscrizione"><br></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
       <td><input type="submit" value="invio" 
action="\lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp"></td></br>
   </tr>
   </table>
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Lista parlamentari di quella circoscrizione</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!--   <form action="getParlamentare4"> -->
     <c:forEach items="${parlamentari}" var="parlamentare" >

<td>Nome:</td>
    <td><c:out value="${parlamentare.getPk().getNome()}"/></td>
    <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Partito:</td>
    <td><c:out value="${pk.partito}"/></td><br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Circoscrizione:</td>
   <c:forEach items="${pk.getCircoscrizione()}" var="CIRCOSCRIZIONE">
      <td><c:out value="${CIRCOSCRIZIONE}"/></td> <br>
       </c:forEach>
   </tr>
   <br>
    <tr>
   <td>Data di nascita:</td>
   <td><c:out value="${parlamentare.data_nascita}"/><br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Luogo:</td>
   <td><c:out value="${parlamentare.luogo}"/><br></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Titolo di studi:</td>
   <td><c:out value="${parlamentare.titolo_studi}"/><br></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mandati:</td><br>
   <c:forEach items="${parlamentare.mandati}" var="mandato">
       <table>
        <tr>
       <td>Mandato:</td> 
       <td><c:out value="${mandato}"/></td><br>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </c:forEach>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
     <td>Commissioni:</td>
      <c:forEach items="${parlamentare.commissioni}" var="commissione">
       <table>
        <tr>
       <td>Commissione:</td> 
       <td><c:out value="${commissione}"/></td><br>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest a tuturial on SPring MVC. One hint a controller **is not a servlet**. So trying to register it as a servlet won't work.

Comment: precisely because I have followed so many tutorials, now I find myself in problems, it should be automatic spring without the need to define a web.xml or am I wrong? Because before it worked even without it.

Comment: Not sure what/which tutorials you followed but if those led you to believe controllers are servlets those are wrong. You need a dispatcherservlet which will figure out which controlle to use and I would strongly suggest to use Spring Boot (and also to ditch JSP). The returned view names in your controllers are also wrong (not that they are working int he first place) the should only be the name of the JSP without the prefix and suffix (the still have .jsp).

Comment: If I remove the .jsp suffix from the methods in the ParlamentareController class, I don't even see the home page with links to other pages. If I remove the suffixes .jsp from the xml file, nothing changes, if I remove it in the action of the page cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione.jsp tells me: unable to find the page, at least so it appears blank. if I comment out the controller servlet in the jsp file, nothing works for me anymore

Comment: As I stated you need the `DispatcherServlet` to do the dispatching to yur controllers. As I also stated I strongly suggest to get a proper guide on how to use Spring MVC because everything in this question shows you are missing crucial information.

Comment: but spring mvc doesn't conflict with hibernate?

Comment: Why should it conflict? Your whole web setup is wrong that has nothing to do with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at least the paths as stated in your view resolver are correct create a configuration class with the following

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.giuggiola")
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    var jspViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    jspViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    jspViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return jspViewResolver;
  }
}
```

Create a class that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and registers this `WebConfig` class.

```java
public class YourInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
  }

  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class}
  }
}
```

This class will bootstrap the `DispatcherServlet` and register the configuration and detect the controllers. In your controllers only return the view name without a suffix/prefix. You should also give the objects you add to the model a name else it will generate a name which is different then what you use in your jsp.

```java
@GetMapping("/cerca_parlamentare_dalla_circoscrizione")
public ModelAndView getParlamentare4(@RequestParam("circoscrizione") String 
 circoscrizionee)
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    List<Parlamentare> parlamentari = 
 parlamRepo.findByCircoscrizione(circoscrizionee);
    mv.addObject("parlamentari", parlamentari);
    mv.setViewName("lista_parlamentari_circoscrizione");       
    return mv;  
}
```

Finally the action in your JSP is wrong as well that shouldn't have the .jsp prefix.

Now ditch that `web.xml` (or whatever contraption that was in your question). Rebuild the app and launch.

That being said I would strongly suggest to use Spring Boot and ditch all that I have shown here and simply add.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public YourApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    var jspViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    jspViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    jspViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return jspViewResolver;
  }
}
```

This will setup Spring Boot which will make it a lot easier to work with your application. When using JSP keep in mind they are dated and have some limitation on embedded systems (see [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations)) and you might even be better off with something like Thymeleaf instead.

Comment: I already had two configuration files like the one you wrote, I deleted them, I also deleted the IndexController class where I was handling errors, I deleted the Beans.xml file.I moved my jsp pages to the new WEB-INF folder that I put inside the webapp folder, I changed the path in the application properties file, I tried to run, but now the start page no longer appears. I used hibernate to define a class of date ranges in the parliamentary model entity class.

Comment: I tried several times to import thymeleaf into the pom, but then it was no longer running the servlets